# method used like a type — error in a unit test

Tags: c#, factory

I am trying to unit test a simple factory, but it keeps telling me that I am trying to use a method like a type. What's going on?

My unit test:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Home;

namespace HomeTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TestFactory
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void DoTestFactory()
        {
            InventoryType.InventorySelect select = new InventoryType.InventorySelect();
            select.inventoryTypes.Add("cds");

            Home.Services.Factory.CreateInventory get = new Home.Services.Factory.CreateInventory();
            get.InventoryImpl();

            if (select.Validate() == true)
                Console.WriteLine("Test Passed");
            else
                if (select.Validate() == false)
                    Console.WriteLine("Test Returned False");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Test Failed To Run");

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

My factory:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Home.Services
{
    public class Factory
    {
        public InventorySvc CreateInventory()
        {
            return new InventoryImpl();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code where the `InventoryImpl` class (and/or the `InventoryImpl()` method) is defined.

Comment: No `== true` and `== false` in tests please, they’re redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to create an instance of the method you're calling *and* then calling the method that it was calling.  Instead, create your factory and then call `CreateInventory`.

```
var factory = new Home.Services.Factory();
var inventory = factory.CreateInventory();
```

- I tend to avoid using `select` and `get` as variable names as they are keywords when used elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

`CreateInventory()` is a method on the `Factory` class.

You are trying to `new` it up - this is not possible.

```
var get = new Home.Services.Factory();
var inventory = get.CreateInventory();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line like you were trying to do.  You were just missing the () after your class name.  Change:

```
new InventoryType.InventorySelect();
```

to

```
new InventoryType().InventorySelect();
```